# Does C++ memset only works for 0 and -1?

Tags: c++, arrays, size, memset

```
int a[2];
memset(a, 3, sizeof(a));
```

when I run this I am getting output as **0 1**. Why not **3 3**

Comment: Please create a [mcve], but note that `memset` works on bytes (i.e. `unsigned char`), not on integers. Consider `std::fill` instead.

Comment: The value produced by this should be `50529027 50529027` on a regular 32/64 bit machine. Are you running this on a microcontroller or something?

Comment: The code provided should not produce any output whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does C++ memset only works for 0 and -1?

It does work for all byte values.

> ```
> int a[2];
> memset(a, 3, sizeof(a));
> ```
>
> when I run this I am getting output as 0 1.

I doubt that. Either your system is broken, or you made a mistake.

> Why not 3 3

Because that's not what `std::memset` does. It sets **every byte** to the value that you provide. A multi-byte integer whose each byte have the value 3 doesn't have the value 3. In the value 3, only the least significant byte would have the value 3 and the more significant bytes would be 0.

Unless you want a repeating byte pattern, `std::memset` won't be useful to you. If you simply want to assign a value to each element, then you should be using `std::fill` or its friends:

```
std::fill(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 3);
```

Or just a bare loop:

```
for(int& i : a)
    i = 3;
```

0 happens to be the only byte pattern that preserves the value across all byte widths on all systems; -1 is another but only on 2's complement systems. On 1's complement systems the other pattern has the value -0. This is why `std::memset` incidentally behaves the same as `std::fill` when using those values and only when using those values.